# Execute Code Written in a jtextarea

Tags: java, jtextarea

I have a jtextarea, and all I want to do is be able to write some code in it (in java) and be able to execute said text as a program

Comment: save the code in a .java file, compile it with  cmd and then execute it via cmd

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you mean to save the code into a .java file. javac processes .java files into .class files

Comment: Try checkout this suggestion : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29709521/1959181 ; you should save the code file using the template in this link and then call this code: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("YourFile.java")` , but it depends on your machine environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java compiler at Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537427/java-compiler-at-runtime)

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790198/how-to-run-groovy-script-in-java

Answer (score 0):

What language do you intend to write/run? If it's javascript, this can be accomplished using ScriptEngine. If it is Java, you'll need to save the code into a file, use javac to generate a .class file, and then use URLClassLoader to load it into your process.

Other languages are going to have other steps, obviously